# instant app getting below 4mb difficulties. how to reduce apk size

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies, android-instant-apps

I am running into difficulties getting the apk below 4mb.
after inspecting the generated instant app APK(s) 
i see that com.google.android.gms.internal is almost 1.4mb. 
i just cannot find the cause of this large chunk. Must be somekind of dependency.

[image]

My base manifest file looks like:

```
dependencies {

api "com.android.support:design:$rootProject.supportLib"
api "com.android.support:support-fragment:$rootProject.supportLib"

api "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.supportLib"
api "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$rootProject.supportLib"
api "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$rootProject.supportLib"

api 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
api "com.google.code.gson:gson:$rootProject.gson"
api "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$rootProject.googleLibs"
api "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:$rootProject.googleLibs"
api "com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:$rootProject.googleLibs"
api "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$rootProject.googleLibs"
api "com.android.support:multidex:$rootProject.multidex"
api "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$rootProject.glide"
annotationProcessor "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$rootProject.glide"
api "com.loopj.android:android-async-http:$rootProject.asyncHttp"

api "org.greenrobot:eventbus:$rootProject.greenRobotEventBus"
api "com.vincentbrison.openlibraries.android:dualcache:$rootProject.dualcache"
api('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

Comment: It can sometimes be useful to run `./gradlew <your_module>:dependencies` to see what the transitive dependencies are in your module....this can show both dependencies that you didn't realise you had and also version mismatches.

Comment: thanks. Yes i am constantly running that command to see where deps are coming from. i am already down from 5mb to 3.2. but i just cannot see anything related to com.google.android.gms.internal 
must be somekind of google lib.  Why is it so big?

Comment: Are you using ProGuard?  You'll find you realistically will need to use it to keep size down for Instant Apps.  As you probably know the 4MB limit is for combination of base and feature apk.

Comment: Yes exactly. Yeah proguard is in use. have it optimised as much as i can. Same for resources. Don't think i can further optimise those a lot. I really need to get rid of some libs and thus probably functionality as well. But i am really wondering why that google stuff is so large. I am fairly sure i don't need it.

Comment: Besides checking through https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size.html to see what else you can do, kabuko's hint at configuration splits might be your next best bet.

Comment: can you check url https://medium.com/google-developers/enabling-proguard-in-an-android-instant-app-fbd4fc014518 might it help you.

Answer (score 5):

I just finished doing the same thing and bringing the Instant Apps size from 13MB to 4MB.

After so much headache and countless hours, I've figured out that size of following packages depends on what dependencies you have included.

1. `com.google.android.gms.internal`
2. `android.support.v4.internal`
3. `android.support.v7.internal`

For example, if you exclude Ads dependency the internal size will be reduced at least 500kb. Same goes for Android support libraries, exclude the CardView and see the support's internal size shrink.

I'll list down all the trouble I went through doing a multi-feature Instant Apps modules of a very large scale app step by step:

**Move Dependencies that only gets used in Main App**

In your case following 2 items are absolutely useless for Instant App and only get's utilized in Main App:

```
api "com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:$rootProject.googleLibs"
api "com.android.support:multidex:$rootProject.multidex"
```

Move them to main app, moving Appindexing could be tough if the code is coupled with your views but that you'd have to fix it. In my case, I had to instantiate AppIndexing from a view in Base Module so I did that using Otto (EventBus). Created an event in Base Module, fired it and caught in Main App's AppIndexing helper class.

**Exclude google support group explicitly from all packages**

It may look absurd but the size speaks for itself, change all Google/Android support dependencies with explicit exclusions:

```
api("com.android.support:design:$rootProject.supportLib") {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
api("com.android.support:support-fragment:$rootProject.supportLib") {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
api("com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.supportLib") {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
api("com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$rootProject.supportLib") {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
api("com.android.support:cardview-v7:$rootProject.supportLib") {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
api('com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
api("com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$rootProject.googleLibs") {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
api("com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:$rootProject.googleLibs") {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
api("com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:$rootProject.googleLibs") {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
api("com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$rootProject.googleLibs") {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
```

**Enable Proguard for each module**

As others have mentioned, [enable proguard for each module](https://medium.com/google-developers/enabling-proguard-in-an-android-instant-app-fbd4fc014518). About 25% of our original 13MB was reduced by proguard.

**Exclude Features that won't be used in Instant Apps**

Login:

For us, the Login functionality didn't need to be in Instant App. So I moved everything related to Login/Auth to main app and used Event Bus to fire actions where needed from Base Module. For example Login/Logout actions in navigation drawer (hidden in Instant App but visible in Main app) are present in Base Module. So I fire an Event for each and catch it in Main App Module to show Login Screen or process logout.

This allowed me to exclude `com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth` dependency from Base Module which reduced the gms internals size even further.

Ads:

We had to move Ads out of our Base Module to main application solely for the size purpose. We did this using the similar technique (Event Bus) to make a call to render Ads from Base Module and doing actual rendering in Main App through a helper class.

This allowed us to remove `com.google.firebase:firebase-core` and `com.google.firebase:firebase-ads`

P.S: The features exclusion totally depends on your needs/want/compromises. We took these decisions as we wanted all of our revenue generating features to be in Instant App. So as long as we can make money we don't care about Ads or Login.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is the dependency tree for com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:

```
\--- com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.8.0
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:11.8.0
```

play-services-ads is a big library (contributing to a lot of code in "com.google.android.gms.internal"), and you might have success by swapping it out for a [smaller library](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/lite-sdk).  (Of course, I'd recommend filing an issue to get an officially-supported "lite" version of "firebase-ads".)

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain that `com.google.android.gms.internal` includes common code used by public gms packages, in your case `com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth` (which you are probably using for Smart Lock) and won't be able to remove it. If you're already down to 3.2MB, honestly I suspect it'll be hard to get much smaller. You seem to be using both Play Services and the support libraries. Between the two of those it's difficult to get it down much more. The other thing which I've found helpful is using [configuration splits](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/guides/config-splits.html), especially density splits.